# Is there a PHP Class That I Can Use to Make Sure My Users Can't Enter the Same Data Twice (Preventing Duplicate Data)?

Tags: php, duplicates, duplicate-data, soundex

**Problem Overview:**

- My application has an enrollment form.
- Users have a habit of entering the same person into the system twice.
- I need to find a way to rapidly and accurately check the data they've entered against the other clients in the database to see if that client is already in the database.

**Criteria Currently Being Used:**

- Duplicate SSN
- Duplicate Last Name and Date of Birth
- Duplicate First Name, Date Of Birth and Partial SSN Match (another client has an SSN where 5 of the 9 digits are the same *and in the same position*.
- Duplicate First Name and Partial SSN Match (another client has an SSN where 5 of the 9 digits are the same *and in the same position*.
- Duplicate Last Name and Partial SSN Match (another client has an SSN where 5 of the 9 digits are the same *and in the same position*.

In addition to these checks, there's been discussion of using soundex to detect matches based on *similiar* first name / last name.

Is there a PHP class already designed to handle something like this? Can something like this be done at a (Mysql) Database level?

**Clarifications:**

- The problem exists not because of a lack of data integrity at the database level but because of typos caused during the entry process. The applicaiton is a data-entry application. Users are taking physical paper copies of forms and entering the data into the application.

Comment: Not sure for PHP class, but for full matches there are `UNIQUE` column specifier in MySQL that prevents inserting duplicates in that column. Works tablewise, but can't handle complex conditions like `if NAME and DOB match - fail, but if NAME match and DOB not match - don't`

Comment: when you're dealing with data duplicates, its less of a validation issue than it is a data management issue... and for that reason, i'll say its something you should deal with using mysql.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your problem correctly the point is that the duplicates you want to filter out are not necessarely equal as strings. I encountered situations like this a couple of times in the past and I could never find a perfect criteria for finding logical duplicates. In my opinion the best way to deal with such cases is to provide a very smart autocomplete-like functionallity to the user, so when he tries to enter the data he sees all the similar entries and he hopefully won't create a new entry for something he see in the  list. Such a soulution can be a good "buddy" of your not-yet-perfect criteria.

Answer (score 1):

Not a php solution, but

You can cast that fields in your database as `unique`.

```
ALTER TABLE  `users` ADD UNIQUE (
    `username`
)
```